# Pass parameter values to table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following stored procedure query and now I need pass some parameter values to the 'details' table columns like "cus_name" and "cus_tel" inside this query in SQL Server.

```
SELECT APO_Order_Id AS              Purchase_Order_Number,
       p.ref_code AS                Project_ID,
       p.PJM_UserDefinedProjID AS   Project_Code,
       CASE m.APO_Use_Alt_Address
           WHEN 0
           THEN LTRIM(isnull(p.PJM_LotNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_StreetNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_SiteAddr1, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Suburb, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_PostCode, ''))
           WHEN 1
           THEN LTRIM(isnull(p.PJM_Alt_LotNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_StreetNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_SiteAddr1, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_Suburb, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_PostCode, ''))
       END AS                       Project_Site_Address,
       p.PJM_StartDate AS           Site_StartDate,
       s.CNT_ClientName AS          Creditor,
       m.APO_Description AS         Purchase_Order_Description,
       isnull(d.Order_Amount, 0) AS Order_Total,
       ui.tui_username AS           Project_Manager
FROM Account_APOrderMaster AS m
     LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT APOD_Master_Id,
           APOD_Project_Id,
           SUM(APOD_Total_Amount) AS Order_Amount
    FROM Account_APOrderDetail
    GROUP BY APOD_Master_Id,
             APOD_Project_Id
) AS d ON m.Ref_Code = d.APOD_Master_Id
     LEFT JOIN Client_Name AS s ON m.APO_Supplier_ID = s.Ref_Code
     LEFT JOIN Project_Master AS p ON d.APOD_Project_Id = p.ref_code
     LEFT JOIN System_UserInformation AS ui ON m.APO_ProjectManagerId = ui.Ref_Code
WHERE apo_order_id = @purchase_order_number
GO
```

How can I do this?

**completed Stored Procedure Codes**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetPurchaseOrderProjectDetails]
@purchase_order_number as varchar(20)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON


SELECT APO_Order_Id AS              Purchase_Order_Number,
       p.ref_code AS                Project_ID,
       p.PJM_UserDefinedProjID AS   Project_Code,
       CASE m.APO_Use_Alt_Address
           WHEN 0
           THEN LTRIM(isnull(p.PJM_LotNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_StreetNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_SiteAddr1, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Suburb, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_PostCode, ''))
           WHEN 1
           THEN LTRIM(isnull(p.PJM_Alt_LotNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_StreetNumber, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_SiteAddr1, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_Suburb, '')+' '+isnull(p.PJM_Alt_PostCode, ''))
       END AS                       Project_Site_Address,
       p.PJM_StartDate AS           Site_StartDate,
       s.CNT_ClientName AS          Creditor,
       m.APO_Description AS         Purchase_Order_Description,
       isnull(d.Order_Amount, 0) AS Order_Total,
       ui.tui_username AS           Project_Manager
FROM Account_APOrderMaster AS m
     LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT APOD_Master_Id,
           APOD_Project_Id,
           SUM(APOD_Total_Amount) AS Order_Amount
    FROM Account_APOrderDetail
    GROUP BY APOD_Master_Id,
             APOD_Project_Id
) AS d ON m.Ref_Code = d.APOD_Master_Id
     LEFT JOIN Client_Name AS s ON m.APO_Supplier_ID = s.Ref_Code
     LEFT JOIN Project_Master AS p ON d.APOD_Project_Id = p.ref_code
     LEFT JOIN System_UserInformation AS ui ON m.APO_ProjectManagerId = ui.Ref_Code
WHERE apo_order_id = @purchase_order_number
GO
```

Comment: Unable to undestand! Do you want the parameters for the where clause to filter the data?

Comment: yes of course. I need insert new values as parameters in the details table

Comment: `@purchase_order_number` where it comes from?

Comment: that is from Account_APOrderMaster table

Comment: This is also a parameter? Then same you have add new params like this for the Stored procedure inputs

Comment: please show the complete stored procedure codes

Comment: actually above stored procedure is used to grab some values from ''Account_APOrderMaster'' table and now I need pass that data and new parameter data to  ''details'' table.

Comment: please see above complete codes

Comment: what do you mean by `pass some parameter values to the 'details' table columns like "cus_name" and "cus_tel" inside this query` ?

Comment: I mean I need insert new data set to ''details'' table  "cus_name" and "cus_tel" using above stored procedure.